# Input automation for Internet Explorer 11

Tags: internet-explorer, macros, internet-explorer-11, userscripts

I'm working on a large web app for which very frequently run tests in IE11. To commence with the test, I need to supply credentials and click the login button, then navigate to a constant URL.

Is there any macro or user script type solution I could use to automate this process? We are not engaging in automated UI testing, so a full framework for that would be overkill and probably add too much complexity and or time. I'm looking more for a user oriented tool versus a developer oriented tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use AutoHotkey, you can script quite a bit in it like logging in.

Here's a forum link which has more details on how to write AHK scripts.

http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/94432-hotkeys-to-login-to-web-pages/